# Key binding help for magit popup-based commands

Tags: key-bindings, magit, help

Magit implements multi-key bindings in a nonstandard way: the first key runs a command that displays a “popup”, i.e. a buffer in a special mode that displays usage instructions, and the second key is bound in that special mode. That second key invokes `magit-invoke-popup-action` which looks up the event that invoked it in a table.

This breaks Emacs's help mechanism: if I want to know what command a key binding invokes, <kbd>C-h c</kbd> or <kbd>C-h k</kbd> isn't helpful. If I use these commands before the first key (the one that brings the popup), I get the help for the command that displays the popup (e.g. <kbd>C-h c c</kbd> → “c runs the command magit-commit-popup”). If I use these commands before the second key (the one that runs in the popup buffer), I get the help for the generic second-key lookup function (e.g. <kbd>c C-h c c</kbd> → “c runs the command magit-invoke-popup-action”). And if I want to look up the key that invokes a command, <kbd>C-h w</kbd> truthfully tells me that the command isn't bound to any key — it's hidden behind the popup.

How can I find out Magit's key binding information from within Emacs? I am not interested in loading the documentation in Info and searching through it. I want to obtain the information automatically, following Emacs's self-documented principles, and accurately even if the documentation isn't up-to-date or I'm using customized key bindings.

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>? <key></kbd>. Inside popups <kbd>?</kbd> is bound to `magit-popup-help`. It would make sense for <kbd>C-h k</kbd> to be bound to that command too. So I have done that now.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to rebind `C-h c` and `C-h k`: it could get confusing. If you do rebind, make it `C-h k`, not `C-h c`, since `?` is analogous to `C-h k`. What about the other direction (`C-h w`)? How do I go from `magit-commit` to `c c`? That's the direction I care most about.

Comment: Indeed, I got the two keys confused. There's no way of going the other way. Complications like this are one of the reasons why I intend to replace `magit-popup` with a better implementation, likely to be named `transient`.